# C* algebras of free semicircular systems

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, free-probability

It was shown by Pimsner and Voiculescu in 1982 that the reduced group $C^{*}$-algebras $C^{*}_{r}(\mathbb{F}_{n})$ and $C^{*}_{r}(\mathbb{F}_{m})$ are isomorphic if and only if $n = m$ (here, $\mathbb{F}_{n}$ denotes the free group on $n$ generators).  The proof of this fact relies on the computation of the $K_{1}$ groups of both algebras, which coincide if and only if $n = m$.

I suspect that if $(x_{1}, x_{2}, \dots)$ forms a free semicircular family with respect to a trace $\tau$, then $C^{*}(x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}, \tau) \cong C^{*}(x_{1}, \dots, x_{m}, \tau)$ if and only if $n = m$.  Certainly any proof of this statement can not rely on the computation of $K$ groups as they are isomorphic.  I am wondering if anyone knows a good reference for this (assuming it is true).

Comment: I just spoke with Ken Dykema, and he informed me that the (non)isomorphism of the $C^*$-algebras generated by different-sized semicircular systems is in fact an open problem!